# What's the best approach to offering a one-off membership discount when using GoCardless direct debit?

Tags: gocardless

I'm using GoCardless to handle membership payments and it's working well. I now want to implement a one-time discount code to encourage membership sign-ups from a targeted group. The code will provide a substantial discount, but it should only work for the first year, such than when the membership is due for renewal, the normal annual fee applies.

However, my assumption is, that because I'm using the GoCardless Direct Debit extension, when the person signs up using the discount code, a mandate will be created for an annual payment at the discounted price. and therefore at the point of renewal the member will be debited again at the discounted rate. Or am I wrong, and somehow the extension understands that I'm looking at a one-off discount?

I can't be the first to have come across this. what's the optimal approach?

Answer (score 1):

We have built an extension for this to update the amount of the membership type amount that doesn't match the membership amount later down the year. However, there is a limitation on this as the subscription can only be updated 10 times at Go cardless.

Comment: Sounds interesting Pradeep. Do you have link for the extension? I'm aware of the cap on numbers of alterations, which isn't an issue for us. I think we'll be OK initially making it on a one-by-one basis as volumes won't be huge, but good to have options.